# How to pass list (string) to the next activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass the data that is on "nombres" to the next menu activity but I don't know how to make an intent of a list with this situation, I have tried some methods but my app crash.

This is my Code.

```
 private  List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();

 public void atomar(View view) {

    EditText textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField);

    nombres.add(textField.getText().toString());

    Log.i("Info", nombres.toString());

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, textField.getText().toString()+" Agregado!, para borrar presiona el nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

 public Button atomar2;

 public void init(){

     atomar2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.atomar2);
     atomar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {



             Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, menu.class);
             toy.putStringArrayListExtra("key", nombres.);

             startActivity(toy);
         }
     });
 }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
```

Comment: send your stack trace

Comment: user1781908 please send your stack trace so we can help you to find crash

Comment: have you registered your second activity in manifest?

Comment: how i register that?

Comment: you Should learn First how to Call Activity and register to manifest. see this artical  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

It will Give you list. may be this helps you.

```
private  List<String> nombres; 
nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
```

set Intent Data As Follows

```
 Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, menu.class);
 toy.putStringArrayListExtra("key", nombres.);
```

Retrieve data to another Activity On create as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> test = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Comment: my app still crash

Comment: where you put ("key", nombres); android studio says to me that cannot solve the method 'putExtra(java.lang.String,...

Comment: it is not put extra .. it is putStringArrayListExtra., is this your log cat error?

Comment: can you show exact error message so that i can help you

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: try this       Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String key =bundle.getString("key");

Answer (score 0):

For passing list from one activity to other activity use below code.

```
 List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
 // add element in list
 Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, menu.class);
intent.putExtra("list", nombres );
```

// In Menu Activity get list inside onCreate

```
ArrayList<String> list= (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
```

Hope these help you.

Comment: crash :( i dont know what happens

Comment: whre you put ("list", nombre); android studio says to me that cannot solve the method 'putExtra(java.lang.String,...

Comment: replace these line from your code toy.putStringArrayListExtra("key", nombres.); to intent.putExtra("list", nombres );